# Pandas merge column where between dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes - one of calls made to customers and another identifying active service durations by client. Each client can have multiple services, but they will not overlap.

```
df_calls = pd.DataFrame([['A','2016-02-03',1],['A','2016-05-11',2],['A','2016-10-01',3],['A','2016-11-02',4],
                        ['B','2016-01-10',5],['B','2016-04-25',6]], columns = ['cust_id','call_date','call_id'])

print df_calls

  cust_id   call_date  call_id
0       A  2016-02-03        1
1       A  2016-05-11        2
2       A  2016-10-01        3
3       A  2016-11-02        4
4       B  2016-01-10        5
5       B  2016-04-25        6
```

and

```
df_active = pd.DataFrame([['A','2016-01-10','2016-03-15',1],['A','2016-09-10','2016-11-15',2],
                          ['B','2016-01-02','2016-03-17',3]], columns = ['cust_id','service_start','service_end','service_id'])


print df_active

  cust_id service_start service_end  service_id
0       A    2016-01-10  2016-03-15           1
1       A    2016-09-10  2016-11-15           2
2       B    2016-01-02  2016-03-17           3
```

I need to find the service_id each calls belongs to, identified by service_start and service_end dates. If a call does not fall between dates, they should remain in the dataset.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
df_test_output = pd.merge(df_calls,df_active, how = 'left',on = ['cust_id'])
df_test_output = df_test_output[(df_test_output['call_date']>= df_test_output['service_start']) 
                      & (df_test_output['call_date']<= df_test_output['service_end'])].drop(['service_start','service_end'],axis = 1)

print df_test_output

  cust_id   call_date  call_id  service_id
0       A  2016-02-03        1           1
5       A  2016-10-01        3           2
7       A  2016-11-02        4           2
8       B  2016-01-10        5           3
```

This drops all the calls that were not between service dates. Any thoughts on how I can merge on the service_id where it meets the criteria, but retain the remaining records?

The result should look like this:

```
#do black magic

print df_calls

cust_id   call_date  call_id  service_id
0       A  2016-02-03        1         1.0
1       A  2016-05-11        2         NaN
2       A  2016-10-01        3         2.0
3       A  2016-11-02        4         2.0
4       B  2016-01-10        5         3.0
5       B  2016-04-25        6         NaN
```

Comment: You could join `df_calls2` with `df_calls` on `call_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with left join:

```
print (pd.merge(df_calls, df_calls2, how='left'))
  cust_id  call_date  call_id  service_id
0       A 2016-02-03        1         1.0
1       A 2016-05-11        2         NaN
2       A 2016-10-01        3         2.0
3       A 2016-11-02        4         2.0
4       B 2016-01-10        5         3.0
5       B 2016-04-25        6         NaN
```

Comment: df_calls2 isn't a real table. It's the output of merging df_calls and df_service and then removing dupes. It's created to show that the method I tried doesn't work.

Comment: Hmmm, you think it works, but finding better solution?

Comment: Ah gotcha - I see what you're saying, that does work, thanks! I had been exploring using a graph https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html